# Angular Json filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Can't seem to solve this one.

Im trying to display an object in json with the json filter like {{object | json}} but nothing shows up. So this is what I have

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="Controller" class="container">
    <form ng-submit="consume()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Drink</label>
            <select ng-model="drink.type" ng-options="type.name for type in drinkTypes | orderBy: 'name'" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
                <option value="">-- choose drink --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Drinker</label>
            <select ng-model="drink.drinker" ng-options="drinker.name for drinker in drinkers | orderBy: 'name'" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
                <option value="">-- choose drinker --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Consume!" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <pre>{{drink | json}}</pre> <!--This is NOT working-->
    <pre>{{drink.type | json}}</pre> <!--This is working!-->



</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

And I'm using this later on:

```
        <pre>{{drink | json}}</pre>
```

but it just shows a blanc. If I specify "drink.type" it shows me type.

```
        <pre>{{drink.type | json}}</pre>

{
  "name": "shot",
  "size": 0.04,
  "alcohol": 0.4
}
```

The thing is I'm adding more stuff than just type and want to display the entire object in json.

Comment: What is the `ng-model` for the area you are trying to output the `drink | json`?

Comment: I added the entire <body> part

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle/pastbin? it's difficult to help you without all the part... how do you initilize your model? how do you define the `drinkTypes` array?... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `drink` object is not define  cause you are out of yours `for-each` options... 
So only the code between your `<select>` knows it ;)

Comment: Thank you! Im not actually sure what you meant but I found the solution. in the controller I had a function called "drink" which I suppose overrode the object.

Thank you!